# Apache Sqoop import from Oracle to hbase bug

Tags: hbase, sqoop, ambari

I have an **Ambari 2.7.4** cluster and I do my data ingestion with **Apache sqoop** from an **Oracle database**, for the most part it works well and the data ingestion is quick but when I try to import 200,000 rows from one table it takes a long time then when I check my cluster in my region- the server is dead and I have to delete the region from hdfs directly for it to work correctly.

I am even more confused because I can import 100,0000 records with four columns in the same cluster.

Comment: I added space to hbase memory and the situation got better but it still fails ocassionally, I am pretty sure it is not a bug in sqoop but hbase because it fails while writing  reading data from hbase with map reduce